# How to disable an application in Apache OFBiz?

Tags: ofbiz

How to disable some of the default applications that come with OFBiz? (In particular the HR application).

Removing `<load-component component-location="humanres"/>` the `applications\component-load.xml` gave me NULL pointer exception when I restarted the application. Searching Google gave me this: http://www.mail-archive.com/user@ofbiz.apache.org/msg05714.html which suggested that I remove the applications directory. I don't want to do that, I simply want to disable an application. I may need to enable it later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not that easy to disable an application or framework components in OFBiz because there are inter-app dependencies, mostly based on entity definitions. In this specific case the error is generated because of dependency from accounting to HR component.

If you really want to disable the component you have to tract down all the dependencies and fix them. Is there a specific reason you want to "disable" HR component? Instead you can remove it fromt the screen by setting app-bar-display="false" and even prevent logging in that application with some permissions for example.

From the other hand, disabling special-purpsoe apps should be straight forward.

Comment: hiding by setting  app-bar-display="false" , i understood but how can I prevent logging with some permissions and yes i am newbie at ofbiz

Answer (score 2):

The other possible solution is comment out your menu drop down (Find out src file using inspect Element in firebug) and the write your own menus (links) in a screen or `*.ftl` which targets to required application URLs).

PS: You can still find the dependency and remove unwanted components but I prefer to do it if you have so much of time.